# Use $error or $invalid in directive template after upgrade to angular 1.3

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We have a custom datetime input directive in our app. After upgrading to angular 1.3 we decided to update this directive to use validators. Our validator works as expected, we can tell from logging and because the form gets invalidated at the right time. However our field does not get the ng-invalid class attached. We found this is happens because $invalid is always empty when used from inside the directive template.

Our directive template looks like this: (the directive contains more fields which I left out for brevity)

```
<span>
   <input type="text" ng-model="date.date" ng-change="checkDateInput();"
       ng-class="{'ng-invalid': $invalid}" ui-mask="9999-99-99"
       placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
   test: {{$invalid}}, {{$error}}
<span>
```

This aproach with `ng-class="{'ng-invalid': $invalid}"` used to work in angular 1.2 but doesn 't work in 1.3.3 and the $invalid and $error contain the proper data when reference from outside directive like this:

```
<div ng-form="testform">
    <customdatetime name="datetime">
    {{testform.datetime.$invalid}} ... {{testform.datetime.$error}}
</div>
```

Why can't we access this data from within the directive and how should we handle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using angular 1.3 ngMessage for form submission errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789299/using-angular-1-3-ngmessage-for-form-submission-errors)