# prevent ngMessage from showing before the form is submitted

Tags: angularjs

How can I prevent the `ngMessages` from showing up until the user has either focused on the input or the form has been submit?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually validate/invalidate the form.

Take a look at [Using angular 1.3 ngMessage for form submission errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789299/using-angular-1-3-ngmessage-for-form-submission-errors)